# "Timeout expired." when run from the program. Works when run from Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, timeout, ssms

My program says the query times out when I run a `COUNT(*)` query.

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding.

But this very program was response about 10 minutes ago. Strange thing is that the exact query works without a timeout when I run it from *Sql Server Management Studio*. So I don't think the table is locked.

The query is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE RunDate='2015-11-01'
```

I am not sure if pasting my program code works here because this very function has been working the entire day.

So how can I resolve this issue and why does this not happen in *SSMS*?

Comment: How long time does it take in SSMS, compared to the time-out?

Comment: @jarlh almost immediately, less than a second.

Comment: Are you timing out when trying to execute the query remotely?  I assume so because you mention your program.  Check out this tech doc. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177457(v=sql.105).aspx